# Can I roll back only MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.1

I took all database backups before starting patching.

We want to update MySQL 5.6.30 to 5.6.32. If we want to roll back to 5.6.30 due to some issues, can we do that?

Would we have to roll back the entire server? Or is there any way just to roll back MySQL?

Comment: yes, of course You can rollback, You don't need rollback all servers. what server OS?

Comment: It's Windows server.Can you please let me know how to doi it?

Answer (score 1):

You can have 2 strategies:

1. Stop MySQL Server and backup (just copy all files to some location) - folder c:/ProgramData/MySQL/data
2. Make a full dump of all databases 
   mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > c:/backups/all_db.sql

p1 - if You plan rollback exactly for 5.6.30,

p2 - if You plan go till the win, best to have both.

then You must have old installer for revert back at any time, You can download it from official archive - https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/

Then You if You decide revert back:

1. Uninstall latest MySQL - by windows tools
2. Install 5.6.30 from previous step
3. Copy folder c:/ProgramData/Mysql/data saved on previous step
4. Start MySQL

If You also make a sql dump - You can use normal restore procedure

```
mysql -u root -p < c:/backups/all_db.sql
```

, but it work much slower than simple file copy.

Comment: Thank You a_vlad...Is it the same procedure for Linux servers too?

Comment: principles the same, just little difference steps for remove latest version, it depend from version of linux. Like apt-get remove mysql-server-5.6.32, apt-get purge and etc for Debian/Ubuntu, but different name of commands for CentOS and other

Comment: just add, personal vision - difference between 5.6.30 and 5.6.32 really minor, so I not see no one reasons for rollback. and in this case look for 5.6.34 - if upgrade, upgrade to latest